# PrintUI.dll Error Handling

Tags: batch-file, error-handling, cmd, rundll32

It seems like the PrintUI.dll has a different error handling system than the typical command. If I try to run a conditional command like:

```
(rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n "foo") & (echo Success) | (echo Fail)
```

This command will evaluate as false but the error alert isn't suppressed. How do I suppress these alerts?

Error:

[image]

Comment: You only need one ampersand and pipe (`&` and `|`)

Comment: +1 That is the correct syntax but it still does not suppress the alert.

Comment: Other then redirecting the output (which doesnt seem possible in batch) I don't think you can do this.

Comment: you can redirect output with `2>&1` but this still does not suppress the alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. You must include Modification Parameter `/q`.

```
(rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /y /n /q "foo") & (echo Success) | (echo Fail)
```

MS Documentation:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057.aspx

Comment: This always returns "Fail" for me, even though the printer get's added successfully. (rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /in /n /q \\servername\%printername%) & (echo Success) | (echo Fail)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to rundll32 and printui.dll is to use the VBS printer utility script that ships with windows: [prnmngr.vbs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725868%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). When using this script no dialogs are created.

Example (running in cmd.exe):

```
cscript %WINDIR%\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prnmngr.vbs -a -p "my printer"
```